# Prove the convergence of the recurrent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The sequence is given by the recurring relation:

$$
x_{0} = 0, x_{1} = 1,  x_{n+1} =  \frac{x_{n} + n x_{n - 1}}{n + 1}  
$$

Prove that the sequence converges and find its limit.

I managed to get the following, but I do not know how to prove convergence

$$
x_{n+1} - x_{n} =  \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}\\
x_{n+1} = x_{n} +  \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} = x_{n - 1} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = ... = 1 +  \sum_{k=1}^ n  \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} =  \sum_{k=0}^ n  \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}
$$

Comment: Great work so far—now convergence follows from the alternating series test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$, then$$x_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nx_{k+1}-x_k=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}=\log 2.$$

Comment: What is the convergence criterion you use here? Please explain why the sequence converges.

Comment: Are you asking why the *series* $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$ converges?

Comment: Yes. And I'm asking, according to what criterion the original sequence converges.

Comment: The series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}$ converges by the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Your sequence converges because you proved that it is equal to seqeunce $\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, which converges, as I explained in my previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x_{n+1} = x_{n} +  \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} = x_{n - 1} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = ... = 1 +  \sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}n}  \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} =  \sum_{k=0}^{\color{red}n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}
$$

The sign alternates and also $\frac1{k+1}$ is a positive decreasing function that congerges to zero, hence by alternating series test, $x_n$ converges.